# let cmake find openmp support from macport-built gcc on OS X 10.9

Tags: gcc, cmake, macports, osx-mavericks

I want to build [ParadiseEO](http://paradiseo.gforge.inria.fr/index.php?n=Main.HomePage) on OS X 10.9. It uses cmake to configure. While it configured, it couldn't find any openmp support:

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 5.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 5.0.0
```

[image]

Looks like it's a problem of Clang. Meanwhile, I do have gcc-4.8 installed through macports with openmp support. My question is, what should I do to make cmake recognize my gcc-4.8?

Comment: Did you tell it to look in `/opt/local`?  (I don't know to do that in cmake as I don't use it, but that's what you'll need to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, what should I do to make cmake recognize my gcc-4.8?

You can use [CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_LANG_COMPILER):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=gcc .
```

Or `CXX` environment variable:

```
export CXX=gcc
cmake .
```